# mvc3 jquery infinity scroll

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, infinite-scroll

I am trying to do an infinity scroll on my page were if users get to a certain section on the page it automatically gets more files from the database, like what facebook does. My code is not working but what can I be missing here is what I have..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{  
 $(window).scroll(function () {
              if ($(window).scrollTop == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                alert('here');
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      url: "Account/feeds"
                  });

              }

          });
 });

</script>

     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("feeds", "Account", new AjaxOptions
 {
UpdateTargetId = "globe",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod = "GET",

  }))
   {

 // my form here
}

}

 <div id="globe">

    </div>
```

My account/feeds is a partialview

```
public PartialViewResult feeds(// attributes)

  {
       // here I just basically get 10 records from the database and return back to the   page                   

    }
```

I know for a fact that the account/feeds works because when the page is loaded I click on the Ajax.Form search and 10 records are loaded but when I scroll to the bottom of the page 10 more records are supposed to load but do not. Which leads me to believe that the Jquery code above is not correct any suggestions?

I have also put **alert here** on the jquery code and it doesnt pop up

Answer (score 0):

Simple change your

```
if ($(window).scrollTop
```

To

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop()
```